# the link of my site which i create on github does not work

Tags: html, css, repository, github-pages, github-release

i am a newcomer plz help fix this; i create two documents (an html & a css that link to the html) for my coursera assignment course4 and upload these documents to my repository in github, set the branch to main and root and get the link (Your site is live at https://om66id66.github.io/) but whene visit site just load content of ReadMe file! and no result from html and css document! what did i not do That these documents do not work? I did not do anything other than what I said above, Do the documents require a special tool or interface to be read?

i do my assignment for coursera and made documents to create a site in github And I expected that the desired link of the site that I created would run correctly, but it doesn't. These documents work fine in live server and text-editors but not in github repository!

Comment: Your solution exists at https://om66id66.github.io/module2-solution.html. If you rename that file to `index.html`, it'll show up directly.